# Jenkins shows "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) Compilation failure"

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I developed the simple maven project in spring tool. I deployed the code in jenkins and create a pipeline for that job. But jenkins failed to compile. I configured JDK in jenkins correctly.

It shows "No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project course-api: Compilation failure"

```
<project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>
      <artifactId>employee-api</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>java brains employee api</name>
       <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    </project>
```

My jenkins pipeline is

```
node{
def mvnHome
stage('git checkout process'){
  echo 'started checkout'
  git 'https://github.com/prakash9707/employee'
  echo 'completed sucessfully'
}

stage('compile package'){
mvnHome = '/opt/apache-maven/bin'
sh "${mvnHome}/mvn package"
echo 'started compiling'
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the withMaven()  pipeline Maven plugin instead of explicitly setting maven for build.

```
withMaven(
        // Maven installation declared in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration"
        maven: 'M3',
        // Maven settings.xml file defined with the Jenkins Config File Provider Plugin
        // Maven settings and global settings can also be defined in Jenkins Global Tools Configuration
        mavenSettingsConfig: 'my-maven-settings',
        mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {

      // Run the maven build
      sh "mvn clean install"

    } // withMaven will discover the generated Maven artifacts, JUnit Surefire & FailSafe & FindBugs reports...
```

Refer [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <configuration>
       <fork>true</fork>
       <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\javac.exe</executable>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Add "maven-compiler-plugin" plugin.
       OR
[Try to add JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ALas.png)